# How to show that $\int_p^x dT \int_{p}^T dt \ f(t) = \int_{p}^x dt\ (x - t) f(t)$

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

Suppose $f(t)$ is continuous on the interval $[p,q]$ and that $p \leq x \leq q$. Formula (4.631) of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik then states that
$$
\int_p^x dT \int_{p}^T dt \ f(t) = \int_{p}^x dt\ (x - t) f(t) \ .
$$
How does one prove this result?

Comment: Use Fubini's theorem after converting to an integral over $[p,x]^2$.

Comment: What is the coordinate change required to map to $[p,x]^2$? As I understand it the above region is a triangle.

Comment: A graph makes it clear, but I'll give you a trick in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Gradshteyn/Rhyzik 4.631)

$$ \int_p^x dt_{n-1} \int_p^{t_{n-1}} dt_{n-2}\   \dots \dots \int_p^{t_1} \ f(t)\ dt  = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \ \int_p^x\ (t-x)^{n-1} \ f(t)\ dt
$$

Using the indicator function $\mathbf{1}_{t \leqslant T}(t,T) = \begin{cases}1, & t \leqslant T\\0, &t > T \end{cases}$ and Fubini's theorem,

$$\int_p^x\ \left(\int_p^Tf(t)\, dt \right)\  dT = \int_p^x \ \left(\int_p^x\ f(t) \ \mathbf{1}_{t \leqslant T}\  dt \right)\ dT=$$
$$\int_p^x \ \left(\int_p^xf(t)\ \mathbf{1}_{t \leqslant T}\ dT\  \right)\ dt = \int_p^x\left(\int_t^xf(t)\, dT 
\right)\  dt  = \int_p^x \ (x-t) \ f(t) \ dt$$